# How to groupby in pandas where i have column values starting with similar letters

Tags: pandas, group-by

Suppose i have a column with values(not column name) `L1 xyy, L2 yyy, L3 abc,` now i want to group `L1, L2 and L3` as L(or any other name also would do).
Similarly i have other values like A1 xxx, A2 xxx, to be grouped form A and so on for other alphabets.
How do i achieve this in pandas?
I have L1, A1 and so on all in same column, and not different columns.

Comment: can you make a sample dataframe and an expected output? also is this in one column or all df columns

Comment: Just one column.

Comment: check the below answer by jez.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted.

Comment: cool. for future reference future, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indexing by `str[0]` for return first letter of column and then aggregate some function, e.g. `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['L1 xyy','L2 yyy','L3 abc','A1 xxx','A2 xxx'],
                   'val':[2,3,5,1,2]})
print (df)
      col  val
0  L1 xyy    2
1  L2 yyy    3
2  L3 abc    5
3  A1 xxx    1
4  A2 xxx    2

df1 = df.groupby(df['col'].str[0])['val'].sum().reset_index(name='new')
print (df1)
  col  new
0   A    3
1   L   10
```

If need new column by first value:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str[0]
print (df)
      col  val new
0  L1 xyy    2   L
1  L2 yyy    3   L
2  L3 abc    5   L
3  A1 xxx    1   A
4  A2 xxx    2   A
```